# Basis of linear maps space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Suppose we have two vector spaces $ X, Y$ over the same field F and $\{{x_i} \} , \{y_j \} $ $(i=1,2...,m ; j=1,2,...,n)$ their bases. Let $L=L(X,Y)$ be the set of all linear maps $f: X \rightarrow Y$. Then defining addition and scalar multiplication (in the obvious way) L becomes a vector space.

How do we then show that the functions $ f_{ij} \in L $ such that $f_{ij} (x_k) = δ_{ki} y_j $ , for $x_k \in \{ x_i \}$, consist a basis of L? ($δ$ is the kronecker delta). I've browsed previous questions but it's still somewhat unclear to me. This is what I've come at:

Let $ f \in L$. Then for any $x_k \in \{ x_i \}$ it holds $$ f(x_k)= \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{kj}y_j     ,\space \space  a_{kj} \in F$$

using our definition of $f_{ij}$ we can show $$ f(x_k)= \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^{m} a_{ij} f_{ij} \space \space (1)$$

How do we proceed? We showed that for any $f$, the images of the base vectors $x_k$ of $X$ are a linear combination of $f_{ij}$. Don't we need to show that something like $(1)$ holds for $f(x), \space x \in X$ and not just for $x_k \in \{ x_i \} $ ?

If we can conclude from $(1)$ that $f= \sum \sum a_{ij} f_{ij}$ please do explain why. Thanks.

Comment: once you have (1), it is easy to conclude: every $x\in X$ can be written as a linear combination of $x_k$ and $f$ is linear. If you write down $f(x) = f(b_1x_1+..+b_mx_m) = b_1f(x_1)+..+b_mf(x_m) = ...$ and regroup, you can deduce the proof